# How do I disable the "Latest News" tab in IncrediBuild for Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, incredibuild

I am using IncrediBuild 5.0 from Visual Studio 2012, and I notice that the IncrediBuild tab has a "Latest News" section that changes text every few seconds, which I find quite distracting while consuming a lot of screen real estate from the IncrediBuild status panel.

[I bet somebody got a really nice bonus for that feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/01/922449.aspx)

The tab has a close button, which in fact does close the tab, only to appear again a while after (not sure if it is after a few days, after a reboot, or after a Visual Studio restart).

Anyways, I can't find any way to completely disable this quite annoying "feature". I have checked all the agent settings and I can't find anything remotely similar to what I'm looking for.

Does anybody know how can I completely disable the "Latest News" tab in IncrediBuild?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 'feature' has annoyed me for ages. A colleague found something:

in your installation folder (Program Files\Xoreax\Incredibuild) check the data\news\news.dat file. There is a flag inside `EnableNews=1`, disable it.